# ionic g pipe search-filter not working in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, pipe, ionic4, generate

I tried to create a pipe filter by using following cli.

```
ionic g pipe search-filter
```

but I get this error message.

> ng generate pipe search-filter --project=app More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into
>   the closest module.

Of course, `ionic g page pages/login` works well
Please let me know how to fix the problem in creating new pipe.
Thank you

Comment: Hi, I don't think this has anything to do with XPages -- perhaps remove the tag or clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
    ionic g pipe search-filter --module app